# Cython compilation with split definition

Tags: c, pointers, cython

I am trying to declare a Cython class in a `pxd` file but can't compile it when I try to assign a pointer.

The following `pyx` compiles fine :

```
cdef class Foo:
    cdef void *_void

    cdef set_ptr(self, void *ptr):
        self._void = ptr
```

But when I split it in 2 files according to the [Cython documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-extension-types) :
**.pxd**

```
cdef class Foo:
    cdef void *_void
    cdef set_ptr(self, void *ptr)
```

**.pyx**

```
cdef class Foo:
    cdef set_ptr(self, void *ptr):
        self._void = ptr
```

I get the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

cdef class Foo:
    cdef set_ptr(self, void *ptr):
        self._void = ptr
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test/test.pyx:5:21: Cannot convert 'void *' to Python object
```

What can I do to make it compile ?

Comment: It works for me with the exact code you posted. Does the name of your pxd file match that of your pyx?

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for your sugestion. The files had indeed the same name, but the problem came from the name of the lib in `setup.py`, which was different from the name of the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making the name of the Extension in `setup.py` the same as the name of the `pxd` and `pyx` files, it solved the issue. It seems that Cyhton was not compiling the `pxd` file otherwise.